# VB.NET 4.0 Parallel.ForEach AddressOf Multiple Values?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, parallel-extensions

I am trying change from Delegates to Parallel.ForEach

I see the below works fine.

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

  Sub Main()
   Dim secs() As Integer = {2, 3, 1}
   Parallel.ForEach(secs, AddressOf Method2)
  End Sub

  Sub Method2(ByVal i As Integer)
   Console.WriteLine(i.ToString)
  End Sub
```

But what if my Sub takes more then one variable? Can you show me  how I should do the below?

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
  Sub Main()
   Dim secs() As Integer = {2, 3, 1}
   Dim Path as String = "Constant"

   Parallel.ForEach(secs, Path, AddressOf Method2)
  End Sub

 Sub Method2(ByVal i As Integer, path as string )
  Console.WriteLine(i.ToString, path)
 End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this via a [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx):

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
  Sub Main()
   Dim secs() As Integer = {2, 3, 1}
   Dim Path as String = "Constant"

   Parallel.ForEach(secs, Sub(sec) Method2(sec, Path))
  End Sub

 Sub Method2(ByVal i As Integer, path as string)
  Console.WriteLine(i.ToString(), path)
 End Sub
```

This will allow the compiler to create a closure that gets the value of Path, and pass it directly into your method.

Comment: Thanks, I can't add an answer yet for 3 more minutes. But I do get that same warning with Sub

Comment: @Jasin Is that warning a Visual Studio warning, or a Resharper/3rd party tool warning?  I suspect it's a false warning...

Comment: VS 2010 Pro, I will be happy to ignore it, just making sure.

Comment: @Jasin The code I have above, exactly as typed, doesn't give that warning in Visual Studio 2010... (And it works correctly).  Do you have Resharper or any extensions installed?

Comment: Productivity Power Tools, Spell Checker. - Perhaps do you think It matters that Path is actually from a ForEach in Paths? - My code is more complex then above, was just trying to get this part right.

Comment: @Jasin: If you want to edit your question or ask another question - post your actual code.  It may matter ,depending on what you're doing... Is this entire thing in a foreach?

Comment: @Jasin: I'd recommend taking your current code, and making a question showing the warning/error and asking why it's causing it (now that this part is fixed)

Answer (score 1):

Certainly in C#, I'd use a lambda expression to call `Method2` instead:

```
Parallel.ForEach(secs, i => Method2(i, path));
```

Whether the equivalent will look elegant in VB is beyond the amount of good judgement I have about a language I don't use at 12.50am, but you don't have a lot of other choices really - assuming you don't want to create an instance of another class, passing `path` into the constructor, and then using a single-parameter method in that class...

(Oh, and another option would be to change `Method2` into a single parameter method where the parameter encapsulated both values. So I guess you *do* have a few options - but in C# at least, the lambda expression one would be the way to go.)

Comment: I converted this to Parallel.ForEach(Directories, Function(i) ScanDirectory(i, Path))

and get this warning (Using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results.  Instead, create a local variable within the loop and assign it the value of the iteration variable.)

Thoughts?

Comment: @Jasin My answer shows the correct syntax for this in VB - you need `Sub(i)`, not `Function(i)`